# What is the blast radius for a Atomic Bomb?

Tags: civilization-5

In *Civilization V*, I have built some Atomic Bombs to drop on my opponent city. However, some of my units are nearby. How far should I move my units in order for them to be safe from my own bomb? *What is the blast radius for a Atomic Bomb?*

Comment: Are you talking about "Atomic Bomb" or "Nuclear Missile" or both? There's two separate nuclear units in the game. I'm not sure if their AOE is the same or not.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Whoa! Didn't even realize there were 2, I'm so new. Thanks, I'll edit the question. I was talking about the Atomib Bomb :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blast radius is the same for both the [atomic bomb](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Atomic_bomb_%28Civ5%29) and the [nuclear missile](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Nuclear_missile_%28Civ5%29) at 2 tiles. The only difference between the two from a combat perspective is that the bomb is treated as an aircraft and the missile is treated as a missile (obviously).